# Dynamics ax2012:How to export data using Runbasebatch

Tags: batch-processing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I'm using Data Import Export Framework in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 in order to export custom data (TestTable) from ax to file. I successfully did that.

Now I want to create a Batch job manually and then assign Batch job tasks for Staging job and Export job to execute this export in background. I don't know how to implement it, now I'm trying to create my own batch by duplicating `Tutorial_RunbaseForm` class.

To learn how to set up execution jobs as batch jobs in AX I've started with Staging job:

```
Processing group > Get staging data > Create new job id > Select batch processing check box
```

and got the following infolog:

> The Staging:ExportAXType-3 job is added to the batch queue.

In `Processing group > Execution history` my job has `waiting` status and when I click on the `view staging data` Staging data shows nothing at this point.

In `System administration > Inquiries > Batch job` I select my job and click on the `View task` button then `Parameters` button and an error is shown:

> Cannot change a batch job that is not in the Withhold state

**Update :**

The export via batch don't work ,i found this error :

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ReflectionCallHelper.MakeNewObjIntPtr(String typeName, IntPtr intPtr)

   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.XppObjectBase.callReturn(KernelCallReturnVal returnVal)

   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.DictTable.Makerecord()

   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.DMFEntityWriter.writeToStaging(String _definitionGroup, String _executionId, DMFEntity entity) in DMFEntityWriter.writeToStaging.xpp:line 46

   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.DMFStagingWriter.execute(String _executionId, Int64 _batchId, Boolean _runOnService, Boolean _calledFrom, Boolean , Boolean ) in DMFStagingWriter.execute.xpp:line 255

   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.DMFStagingWriter.@execute(String _executionId, Int64 _batchId, Boolean _runOnService, Boolean )

   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.DMFStagingWriter.execute(String _executionId, Int64 _batchId, Boolean _runOnService)

   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.DMFStagingWriter.runOnServer(String _executionId, Int64 _batchId, Boolean runOn) in DMFStagingWriter.runOnServer.xpp:line 3

   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.DMFStagingWriter.Run() in DMFStagingWriter.run.xpp:line 22

   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.BatchRun.runJobStaticCode(Int64 batchId) in BatchRun.runJobStaticCode.xpp:line 54

   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.BatchRun.runJobStatic(Int64 batchId) in BatchRun.runJobStatic.xpp:line 13

   at BatchRun::runJobStatic(Object[] )

   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ReflectionCallHelper.MakeStaticCall(Type type, String MethodName, Object[] parameters)

   at BatchIL.taskThreadEntry(Object threadArg)
```

Comment: Try to rephrase your question with a specific problem, because requests for tutorials are not considered [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at stack overflow. Also as far as I know the DIXF framework already has batch support for export, can you explain why you can't use it?

Comment: Thank you for reply ,please see my edite  1

Comment: Unfortunately I still do not know what your specific problem is, but I suggest you learn about [batch processing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731793.aspx) first before you use it to automate DIXF.

Comment: here i can do export manully ,but when i want to try export by using batch job of the standard so far isn't work, please can you see my update i post the error.thank you

Comment: The error indicates that no new record could be created for your custom table. Because according to you this works when you execute the export not as a batch job, I suggest to make sure that the complete CIL compilation executed without a problem.

Comment: yah the export works manually ,but don't works when i use batch. And i test to do this by entity customer that using `DMFCustomerEntityClass`  and batch work he populate data into staging table

Comment: i excute incremental CIL and the compelation can't finished i get this error : `CIL generation: Value cannot be null.Parameter name: parameterTypes  path :\XppIL`

Comment: Ok, so try a complete CIL compilation.

Comment: I get the some error. it possible to create a custom batch job for my export and attach it to menu item

Comment: Possible yes, but I do not think it is a good idea. You first need to get your CIL compiled (try deleting the xppil folder with the previous compilation). Then you need to understand batch processing and verify that your system can execute batch jobs. Then you can test DIXF export with batch. And then you have the necessary information to decide if you need a custom batch job. If you try to take shortcuts, you will regret it later (research "technical debt").

Comment: ok,thank you for advise,Ihave two question : `1.`  deleting XPPil folder can be cause some problems?  `2.` Using DMF Data can be exported from multiple companies at the same time ?

Comment: stack overflow says that we should avoid extended discussions in the comments and I agree. This has strayed quite a bit from your original question. If you have trouble compiling CIL, please create a new question. And first try to figure out exporting data from one company before your wonder how to do exporting from multiple companies.